# PythonでCSVファイルの列データ読み込み時にエラー: list index out of range

Tags: python

csvファイルの読み取りについてお尋ねしたいのですが

```
import csv
    
f = open("test2.csv", "r",)
reader = csv.reader(f)
    
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    
f.close()
```

現在このような形でcsvファイルを読み込んでおり、読み込みには成功しています。

ここからE列にいくつ10以上数値があるかをカウントしたいと思っております
そこで

```
import csv
f = open("test2.csv", "r", )
reader = csv.reader(f)
count = 0
for row in reader:
    colE = int(row[5])
    if colE >= 10:
        count += 1
        print(count)
        
f.close()
```

としてみたところ、"list index out of range" というエラーがでました。これはどういうことなのでしょうか、またどこか間違っている個所があれば教えていただきたいです。

以下のようなcsvファイルです

```
ダウンロードした時刻：2019/10/16 12:01:46                  
                    
寺泊  寺泊
年   月   日   時   風速(m/s) 風向
                    
2018    2   12  1   10.1    西北西
2018    2   12  2   9.1 西
2018    2   12  3   10  西
2018    2   12  4   11.4    西
2018    2   12  5   10.4    西
2018    2   12  6   10.8    西
2018    2   12  7   11.1    西
2018    2   12  8   12.4    西
2018    2   12  9   11.5    西北西
2018    2   12  10  11.2    西
2018    2   12  11  8.9 西北西
2018    2   12  12  8.1 西北西
2018    2   12  13  5.7 西北西
2018    2   12  14  6.3 西北西
2018    2   12  15  5.5 西北西
2018    2   12  16  7.1 西北西
2018    2   12  17  7   西北西
2018    2   12  18  6.4 西北西
2018    2   12  19  8   西北西
2018    2   12  20  8.6 西北西
2018    2   12  21  7.9 西北西
2018    2   12  22  8.7 西北西
2018    2   12  23  8.9 西
2018    2   12  24  10.1    西
2018    2   13  1   5.2 北西
2018    2   13  2   7   西北西
2018    2   13  3   6.4 西北西
2018    2   13  4   5.4 北西
2018    2   13  5   5.4 北西
2018    2   13  6   3.9 北西
2018    2   13  7   3.5 北西
2018    2   13  8   1.2 北
2018    2   13  9   3   北西
2018    2   13  10  3.4 北西
2018    2   13  11  3.1 北西
2018    2   13  12  4   北西
2018    2   13  13  1.9 北西
2018    2   13  14  2.2 北西
2018    2   13  15  2.1 北西
2018    2   13  16  2.7 北西
2018    2   13  17  2.3 西北西
2018    2   13  18  0.5 西
2018    2   13  19  4.9 西北西
2018    2   13  20  9.9 西
2018    2   13  21  11.1    西
2018    2   13  22  8.3 西北西
2018    2   13  23  10.1    西
2018    2   13  24  7.7 西
```

Comment: CSVファイルとの事ですが、実際にはカンマではなくスペースで区切られているのでしょうか？

Comment: カンマで区切られています。

Comment: そうですと、`colE = int(row[5])` は `colE = float(row[4])` にすべきかと(index は `0` から始まります)。また、pandas パッケージが利用できるのであれば、`import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')` として、`len(df[df['風速(m/s)'] >= 10.0])` と書くこともできます。

Comment: また、CSVファイルの先頭にヘッダと空行があるので、これをスキップする必要があります。`reader = csv.reader(f)` の直後に `next(reader); next(reader)` を入れるなど(2行スキップ)。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。colE = float([4])にしてみたところ変わらずcolE = float(row[4]) IndexError: list out of rangeとでてしまいます。１０以上のデータを取り出したい行が６行目から始まるので、reader = csv.reader(f) の直後に next(reader); next(reader);next(reader);next(reader);next(reader)で５行スキップしてみるといいですか？

Comment: はい、5行スキップしてみて下さい。

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

> list index out of range というエラー

これは、IndexErrorを指していますね？（エラーは正確に貼り付けた方が回答が得られやすくなります）

IndexErrorはシーケンスアクセス時に範囲外の要素を参照した場合に送出されます。

[組み込み例外 — Python 3.8.0 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError)

記載されたコードにおいて、シーケンスへのアクセスは6行目の `colE = int(row[5])` のみなので、ここでのアクセス時に問題があるようです。

さて、このコードを修正する方法ですが、

- そもそもE列に対応する添字は4なので、それを修正する（5だと西北西などがヒットするはずです）
- `print(len(row))` などしてみて、おかしい値が読み込まれていないか調べる
- `if len(row) != 5: sys.exit()` のように、長さがおかしい列を見つけたら終了するように作り変える

などが考えられます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。次回からは回答者の方にも伝わるよう意識しようと思います。助かりました！

Answer (score 1):

参考までに、[pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)で処理する方法を挙げておきます。

`read_csv()` には `skiprows` というパラメータがあって、読み込みをスキップする行数を指定することができます。上記の CSV データの場合、先頭の3行は不要で、4行目をヘッダとして読み込む事になりますので、`skiprows=3` を指定します。なお、`read_csv()` ではデフォルトで空行を無視します(`skip_blank_lines=True`)。

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', skiprows=3)
count = df[df['風速(m/s)'] >= 10.0].shape[0]

print(count)
```

**追記**

> 途中でE列に値の無いセルがあると、エラーがでてしまい止まってしまいます。

例えば、以下の様な行がある、という事かと思います。

```python
2018,2,12,6,,西
```

この場合、for loop 内で E 列(風速)に値があるかどうかを調べて、値が無ければデータの次の行を調べる様にします。

```python
import csv

f = open("test2.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)
[next(reader) for _ in range(5)]

count = 0
for row in reader:
  if not row[4].strip(): # confirm if column E has no value
    continue
  colE = float(row[4])
  if colE >= 10:
    count += 1

print(count)
f.close()
```

ちなみに、pandas のデータフレームの場合では空欄は `NaN` として扱われる事になります。

Comment: import csv

f = open("test2.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)
next(reader); next(reader); next(reader); next(reader); next(reader)

count = 0
for row in reader:
    colE = float(row[4])
    if colE >= 10:
        count += 1
        print(count)

f.close()
現在上記のような形で読み込んでいるのですが、途中でE列に値の無いセルがあると、エラーがでてしまい止まってしまいます。この問題は上記のコードを修正することで解決しますでしょうか？

Comment: 途中の空行をスキップしたいという意味です

Comment: 解決しましたありがとうございます。